# How to use htaccess to change image paths?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a html file that has an image:

```
<img src="../smilies/happy.gif" />
```

Is it possible to redirect this path to another using `.htaccess`?

So the above example would become equivalent to

```
<img src="http://static.example.com/smilies/happy.gif" />
```

Comment: why can't you do this in PHP ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you might get away with redirecting all calls that end with `/smilies/happy.gif` to that directory, so it wouldn't matter where the call came from. That does mean you should not wish to call this to some other subedirectory, but I imagine you don't.

something like this (guessing here, cann't test, so read up on the rwriting there :)

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/images/$(.*) http://static.example.com/smilies/$2 [L,R=301]
```

basically you are rewriting everything that has '/images/' in it to that static adress, pasting whatever was after images after the new asdress (the $2 thingy) and then indicating that this is the last command to parse (to stop strange things in the htaccess) and that you want a 301 (permanently moved) code to be sent.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.htaccess`... could you provide an example?

Comment: Just did :). @adarshr 's exmaple prolly works too, although I would use the 301 code.

Answer (score 1):

I think its easier to set a variable in your config

```
<?php 
$static_url = "http://static.example.com/";
?>
<img src="<?php echo $static_url; ?>/smilies/happy.gif" alt="" />
```

Its better then you have the control what came from static and the rewrite engine is slow when you call it everytime its not sooo good.

Comment: While I can modify the file, it would be a pain to modify a whole forum system (vBulletin) that has already 200k posts.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule    ^(smilies/.*)$    http://static.example.com/$1 [R]`

Comment: Almost. It may start with `..` as the example I provided shows. `^smilies` will probably never match :P