# .htaccess referencing images from subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'll try to make this brief. This is my first attempt using HTACCESS to create "user-friendly URLs". I've set up my .htaccess file so that when a user clicks a link that *appears* to be in a subfolder, it loads a file within the root.
ex:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^current-communities/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

So if I click a link like "/current-communities/my-community it will load the file "my-community.php". No problem there.
However, now I'm trying to make another rule that when I click a "floor-plans" link, the floor-plans.php file will load data from a database based on its querystring:

```
    RewriteRule ^floor-plans/([^/]+)-([^/]+).php floor-plans.php?communityname=$1&modelname=$2 [NC]
```

So if a user clicks on a link like "/floor-plans/my-community-myhouse", it will load the "floor-plans.php" file, with "my-community" as the first querystring variable, and "myhouse" as the second.

The issue I'm having here is that the "floor-plans.php" file is not showing the pictures. It is looking into a folder called "images" for graphics, but because "images" is actually within the root directory, I only get a very empty page, but for some reason this is not the issue with the virtual directory of "current-communities". 
Can you help?

Comment: Possible repeat see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207069/how-to-use-htaccess-to-change-image-paths

Comment: change your image urls from relative to absolute: /images/here.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hello try using the next code in the head of your document, basically what it does is to set path for all scripts and css files to the actual root of the php document and not what the address in the browser is set up to your using.
so what it actually does is once set in the head before importing anything else php will automatically set the path if you give on css/style.css, php will set it before it goes back to the browser to http://www.myweb.com/css/style.css

it works fine for my wbesites hope it helps you.

```
<BASE href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
```