# WordPress Move to WordPress Network

Tags: php, wordpress, image, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a very interesting issue. I migrated a website from a normal WordPress installation to a WordPress Network. The main issue I'm having is folder structure.

The specific issue is with images. So here is an example:

Old Image Path: 
***/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg*** or ***/wp-content/uploads/year/month/image.jpg***

With the network, the above paths were changed:

New Image Path:

***/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITE-ID/image.jpg*** or ***/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITE-ID/year/month/image.jpg***

The problem I'm having is that Google indexed all the images according to their old URLs. We get a lot of leads from Google images because people search in images for our products and then end up at our website.

I have tried a rewrite rule like this one to fix it:

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*).(png|jpg|gif) /wp-content/uploads/sites/4/$1.$2 ;
```

However, the issue with the above is that it's now rewriting working images as well:

`https://www.my-webiste-url/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2018/08/image-300x300.jpg` is being rewritten to `https://www.mysite-url/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/image-300x300.jpg` (the problem is because of the year and month that is also included in the URL.

Does anyone have some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a *negative lookahead assertion* in the regular expression to discard matches that include the `/sites/` literal.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(?!sites/)(.*\.(png|jpg|gif))$ /wp-content/uploads/sites/4/$1;
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your comment. I'm just trying to understand this. So you're saying to add the regex when it comes to a request with /sites/ in the URL? So it rewrites all requests, except requests with "/sites/" that will already work.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. The rewrite in my answer is a tweak to the rewrite you have already tested.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks, it works. However, it doesn't work for all the URLs. If I can just give the practical examples:

I have 3 images:

/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4918-1.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_4918-1.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/IMG_4918.jpg

When I visit:

http://www.my-side/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4918.jpg

It works correctly and rewrites the image to /wp-content/uploads/sites/4/IMG_4918.jpg

However, /wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_4918-1.jpg is still giving a 404 error.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: You may find it useful to add rewrite logging. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log).

Comment: This is what I'm seeing:

2018/08/13 19:42:35 [error] 232163#0: *22056835 open() "/var/www/vhosts/webdev4u.co.za/www.webdev4u.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/04/2018/04/IMG_4918.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.11.14, server: webdev4u.co.za, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/04/IMG_4918.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.webdev4u.co.za"

So, from what I can see, it's throwing away the "sites" portion and looking for the  file in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try from **Settings > Permalinks** in WordPress admin.

Comment: OR use this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207069/how-to-use-htaccess-to-change-image-paths

Comment: Hi Jigar, thanks for the response. :-) However, the suggested solution won't work for this specific issue.